# Kafka consumer groups and partitions

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I'm having trouble to grasp the relationship behind partitions and customer groups.

The ideas by themselves are pretty clears, each message that's pushed to a topic gets replicated to all of it's partitions, right?
That way, if two different clients connect to two different partitions of the same topic then they should consume and commit the same messages without interrupting each other.

Consumer groups, as i understand, are abstractions to the idea of partitions and they essentially promise the same thing, two different clients that connect to two different consumer groups of the same topic should consume and commit the same messages without interrupting each other.

So as i see it, it should follow that two clients that connect to the same consumer group would consume messages from the same partition and two clients that connect to two different consumer groups would consume from two different partitions (given that there are at least two partitions for that topic) because otherwise the idea of consumer groups doesn't comply with the idea of partitions.

However, when i run a simple consumer client in C#

```
string group = Console.ReadLine();

            var config = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "group.id", group },
                { "bootstrap.servers", "10.0.0.3:9092" },
                { "enable.auto.commit", true },
                { "auto.commit.interval.ms", 1000 }
            };

            using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
            {
                consumer.Subscribe(new List<string>() { { "myFirstTopic" } });
                while (true)
                {
                    Message<Null, string> msg;
                    if (!consumer.Consume(out msg, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {msg.Topic} Partition: {msg.Partition} Offset: {msg.Offset} {msg.Value}");
                }
            }
```

I get this result:

[image]

The same consumer group consumes from 2 different partitions.
When i run two clients that consume from different consumer groups (a and b) i get this:

[image]

Two different consumer groups consume from similar partitions.

I don't understand how it happens, doesn't it mean that the idea of consumer groups and the idea of partitions contradict one another?

If the same message appears in two different consumer groups under the same partition, doesn't it mean that the same message was inserted twice to the same partition?

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your understanding of consumer groups is correct, but the details in partitions need a bit of clarification.

> The ideas by themselves are pretty clears, each message that's pushed to a topic gets replicated to all of it's partitions, right?

Not exactly. A message will be written to a single partition (and its replicas). All of the messages written to the topic will be split between the topic's partitions. Thus, each partition will only contain a subset of all the messages written to the topic.

Note that replicas are just a way to ensure availability for your data in Kafka cluster in case a Kafka node goes down. It does not affect the message processing semantics.

> So as i see it, it should follow that two clients that connect to the same consumer group would consume messages from the same partition...

Kafka will only allow one client to consume from a partition at a time. Therefore, none of the clients in the same consumer group will consume data from the same partition. However, they can consume from more than one partition at a time. Also, if you have more clients than partitions in a single group, some of the clients will not get any data at all because there is no partition for them to consume data from.

Since a partition only has a subset of the data and it's only assigned to a single client at a time, each client will consume a unique subset of the data written to the topic. Thus, you could say that the multi-partition with single consumer group arrangement works similar to the worker pattern.

Partitions in Kafka drive the parallelization factor for your message processing. The more partitions your topic has, the more clients you can have working in parallel.

> ...and two clients that connect to two different consumer groups would consume from two different partitions (given that there are at least two partitions for that topic) because otherwise the idea of consumer groups doesn't comply with the idea of partitions.

If you have clients in different consumer groups, they can consume from the same partitions. Therefore, all of the consumer groups will receive the same set of data. Multiple consumer groups arrangement is similar to the fan-out pattern.

> Kafka guarantees order of messages, right? How does it work with multiple partitions for the same topic? In-fact, i've seen for myself that it's not always true, is it true only for a single partition?

Your observations are correct. Message ordering can only be guaranteed per partition. Luckily, messages with the same key will end up in the same partition, so you can guarantee ordering by key.

For example, let's assume that you have a topic for all forum post comments. If you only care about ordering of comments within a single forum post, you can select the forum post identifier as the message key for all the comments.

> I read that when i commit an offset, it is committed as part of the partition and not the consumer group, so if i commit an offset in one group, will it affect the offset of another if it pulls from the same partition?

The offsets are stored per partition AND consumer group, i.e. a consumer group can have its own offset for a partition. This way the offsets will not overlap between groups.

Comment: I hope this answer makes it more clear on what's going on. I'll gladly add more details if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, i think i understand better the relationship between groups and partitions. I still have some things that are unclear to me.
1. Kafka guarantees order of messages, right? How does it work with multiple partitions for the same topic? In-fact, i've seen for myself that it's not always true, is it true only for a single partition?
2. I read that when i commit an offset, it is committed as part of the partition and not the consumer group, so if i commit an offset in one group, will it affect the offset of another if it pulls from the same partition?

Comment: @Arik I added some more details to my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @JaakkoPallari amazing answer! One question remains in my mind about ordering: if the the node receives message 1 for partition A, message 2 for partition B, and message 3 for partition A. Is there any chance that somehow partition A would have had message 3 placed in its queue before message 1?

Comment: @payne thanks, glad you found it useful! As far as I understand it, message 3 can’t be placed before 1 unless the node receives message 3 first. If you end up seeing 3 before 1 in your partition, I suspect that the message producer might write them out of order.